# Does this graph contain a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm working on graph theory and I've encountered a challenge in determining whether a given graph contains a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, which would imply that the graph is non-planar by Kuratowski's theorem.

I have a graph (attached below) with 11 vertices and a number of edges, and I am unsure how to identify such subdivisions effectively.

Could someone assist in checking whether this graph has a subdivision of either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ and explain the methodology for identifying such a subdivision? Understanding the process would greatly aid in my comprehension of non-planar graphs and Kuratowski's theorem. I looked at other questions and I tried to identify vertices of degree 4, which would be the original vertices of $K_5$ in its subdivision for example but I'm not sure.

Here's the graph:

[image]

Any insights or strategies for identifying these subdivisions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @KentaS Kuratowski' theorem involves subdivision of the graphs. That means that $K_5$ needs not to be exactly a subgraph. For example, one could collapse the edge $2-9$ and the new vertex would have $4$ edges.

Comment: Yes I agree, I forgot this part.

Comment: As an aside, https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/ is a convenient tool for trying to unravel such a graph if it were in fact planar.  This one is not.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I have been using csacademy.com/app/graph_editor but no luck in finding the subdivisions

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to view this, but one I came up with was by collapsing $3,7,10,11$ all into one vertex, and collapsing $1,5,8$ into one vertex.

The resulting graph before collapse could be viewed as the following:

[image]

Actually performing the collapsing

[image]

Here we can see $K_{3,3}$, albeit with more edges.  $4,6,9$ on one part and $1,2,3$ in the other part with edges between.

In fact, by going further and collapsing $2$ with $9$ we can also rearrange to find $K_5$ present as well.
[image]